# PHP Update Page - Info/Image not updating

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, sql-update

I am at a loss as to what I need to do to get this to work. This page is supposed to update the information on a contact after the update button has been clicked. It feeds the id number into the page, it reads the info from the database and puts it in the inputs as values. Then you update the inputs as needed and it updates it to the server. But it's not executing the Update statement for some reason and nothing is changing. It should also be able to upload an image and make it part of the update.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['message'] = '<div class="message">Your contact has been updated</div>';

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ssl;port=8889', 'root', 'root');

    $contactid = $_GET['id'];

    $stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM contacts where contactid = :contactid");
    $stmt->bindParam(':contactid', $contactid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
      $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $address = $_POST['address'];
      $city = $_POST['city'];
      $state = $_POST['state'];

      $target_file = "uploads/" . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
      $picture = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
          echo "<div class='message2'>File Uploaded.</div>";
      }
      //SQL statement to update data
      $stmt=$dbh->prepare("UPDATE contacts SET firstname='" . $firstname . "',
                                               lastname='" . $lastname . "',
                                               phone='" . $phone . "',
                                               email='" . $email . "',
                                               address='" . $address . "',
                                               city='" . $city . "',
                                               state='" . $state . "',
                                               picture='" . $picture . "',
                                              WHERE contactid='" . $contactid . "';");
      $stmt->execute();

      echo "<div class='message'>Your contact has been added!</div>";

      header("location: index.php");
      die();
    }
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Update</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <nav>
           <h1>Update A Fruit</h1>
         </nav>
         <form id="form" action="index.php" method="post">
             <p>Edit the following:</p> <br />
             First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $result[0]['firstname']; ?>" /><br />
             Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $result[0]['lastname']; ?>" /><br />
             Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $result[0]['phone']; ?>" /><br />
             Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $result[0]['email']; ?>" /><br />
             Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $result[0]['address']; ?>" /><br />
             City: <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $result[0]['city']; ?>" /><br />
             State: <select id="state" type="text" name="state" value="">
                                                 <option value="" selected>Select a State</option>
                                                 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                                 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                                 <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                                 <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                                 <option value="CA">California</option>
                                                 <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                                 <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                                 <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                                 <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                                 <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                                 <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                                 <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                                 <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                                 <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                                 <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                                 <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                                 <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                                 <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                                 <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                                 <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                                 <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                                 <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                                 <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                                 <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                                 <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                                 <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                                 <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                                 <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                                 <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                                 <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                                 <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                                 <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                                 <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                                 <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                                 <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                                 <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                                 <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                                 <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                                 <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                                 <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                                 <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                                 <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                                 <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                                 <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                                 <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                                 <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                                 <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                                 <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                                 <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                                 <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                                 <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                             </select><br>
             <input type="file" name="picture" value="<?php echo $result[0]['picture']; ?>"><br />
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
         </form>
         <a href="index.php">Go Back</a>

         <pre>
           <?php var_dump($st); ?>
         </pre>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
         <script>

             $('.message').fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(600);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are few things you need to change in your code, such as:

- Change the `action` of your `<form>` in the following way,

  ```
  action="index.php?id=<?php echo $contactid; ?>"
  ```
- You won't be able to upload any file with your form unless you include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>`.

  So based on the above two statements, your `<form>` element would be like this:

  ```
  <form id="form" action="index.php?id=<?php echo $contactid; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ```
- Make use of placeholders in your `UPDATE` prepared statement.
- Perform the `UPDATE` operation **before** the `SELECT` operation, otherwise you won't be getting updated values in your `<input>` fields once you update them.

Comment: How could I forget about the enctype attribute? I didn't know about the first change but I should have known about the second one. Let's see if it works.

Comment: Okay that did make sense to add those parts. But it still isn't working.

Comment: @MattLee Which part is not working? `UPDATE` or upload?

Comment: Nothing is changing. So I'm assuming neither.

Comment: I know the upload isn't working because the new image isn't showing up in the uploads folder.

Comment: @MattLee 1. Is the URL correct when you hit the *Update* submit button? 2. Do `var_dump($_FILES);` to check whether the uploaded file information is there or not 3. `echo` out your `UPDATE` query, like `echo "UPDATE contacts SET ...";` and make sure it's correct.

Comment: Okay I made a couple changes. Not exactly sure what I did but now it's actually doing something. Sort of. Instead of updating the contact it's supposed to, it's copying the contact as a brand new one and making the changes to the new one.

I've edited the post to have my current code.

Comment: That was because my form action was going to index.php. update.php is the file I want the data to go to. But when I try that all I get is a blank page with the "File Uploaded" message. The header should make it redirect back to index.php.

Comment: @MattLee Your new `UPDATE` query is wrong, please revert the `UPDATE` query back to [revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41905275/1). Also, if your requirement is - *update.php is the file I want the data to go to.*, then change your `<form>` element in the following way, `<form id="form" action="update.php?id=<?php echo $contactid; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: When you say version 1 do you mean with all the extra double quotes I took out?

Comment: @MattLee Yes, that's correct. Your previous query was syntactically correct.

Comment: Alright so after undoing those changes to the `UPDATE` statement, it is now making the changes I am asking it to make. But it's still not making use of the header. It isn't redirecting back to index.php. It just stays on a white screen with the "File Uploaded" message. I have to use the address bar to get it to go back so I can see the changes.

Comment: @MattLee Don't use `die();` after `header(...);`, `die();` will terminate the execution of the page. Use `exit();` after `header(...);` to redirect the user back to *index.php* page. Also, don't output anything before `header(...);`, otherwise you'd get *headers already sent* error.

Comment: @MattLee I've updated your question and revert it back to revision 1, so that the answer could correctly address your question. It would also make this thread useful for future visitors of SO.

Comment: You have helped me A LOT. After some more messing around it finally works. Everything is doing what it's meant to. You helped me a lot to arrive at this result. Thanks so much. I'm going to give you the check mark.

Comment: @MattLee Glad I could help. :-)